# Validate message with php

Tags: php, validation

I have the following code to validate a message. The message passes and return true even if the message is not valid.

Code:

```
$message = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ 1234567890 \" ' ! & ( ) @ [ ] ? . : , ; - _";

if(isset($message) && strlen($message) > 10)
{
  if (preg_match("/[a-zA-Z0-9 \"'!&()@[\]\?.:,;\-_]/u", $message)) 
  { 
    return true;
  }
  else
  {
    return false;   
  }
}
else
{
  return false;
}
```

The current code should pass as true, all charcters are valid, but when I change the message

```
$message = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ 1234567890 \" ' ! & ( ) @ [ ] ? . : , ; - _ >";
```

It should fail with the last character. But it passes through ands send true. I might be missing something or not escaping something.

Ultimately the message will be send through a HTML form.

UPDATE:

changing the regex to

> preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9 \"'!&()@[]\?.:,;-_]+$/u", $message)

or

```
if (preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9 \"'!&()@[\]\?.:,;\-_]*$/u", $message))
```

Fixed the validation, Didn't think of the multiple occurrences of characters.

Comment: Are you trying to protect yourself from exploit? bit overkilll, [htmlspecialchars()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) would suffice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the preg match to the following:

```
preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9 \"'!&()@[\]\?.:,;\-_]+$/u", $message)
```

The ^ character in the preg match forces the regex to start reading from the beginning of the string and the dollar '$' forces the regexp to look until the end of the string.

Added the + character before the dollar '$'. This accepts multiple characters in the string

Comment: Adding this then return false for both valid and not valid text

Comment: Ah, wait, I'm gonna test :) !

Comment: Edited the answer, added the + character before the dollar ($).

Answer (score 0):

you should add start of string(^), end of string character($) and * to denote multiple occurances of the character in the string. there are multiple spaces in the message string.

```
if (preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9 \"'!&()@[\]\?.:,;\-_]*$/u", $message))
```

Comment: And what about the ^ at the beginning of the message :) ?

Comment: Both worked with a simple random text such as "kjdshkjfh 12" I will be going through extensive testing of the form, If I encounter problems I will be switching through the solutions. At this point both seem to work to perfect. thanx for the solution you gave :)

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression says, that any string, which contain any one of characters

> "a-zA-Z0-9 \"'!&()@[]\?.:,;-_"

will be valid. But actually we need to figure out if string contains of any other symbol. For this you can just put "^" at the begining of the sybmols class and check string to be not matching our regexp.
Here the code:

```
if(isset($message) && strlen($message) > 10) {
if (!preg_match("/[^a-zA-Z0-9 \"'!&()@[\]\?.:,;\-_]/u", $message)) { 
return true;
}
else {
return false; 
}
}
else {
return false;
}
```

Or just change your regexp with this -

> "/^[a-zA-Z0-9 \"'!&()@[]\?.:,;-_]+$/u",

where i added literals:

```
^ - begin of the string,
+ - quantifier, which means, that there must be at least 1 symbol (you can use *, as well, cause you check lenght of the string),
$ - end of the string.
```

Advise - check a